# SMO FileGroup.Files produces DuplicateNameException

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, smo

For my ASP.net application, I am implementing a way of automatically cloning the production database, using SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) library code. I am doing this by backing up the database, and then restoring it to a different database on the same server. As part of this, I use the relocateFiles collection to specify the location of the data file and log file for the new database.
This all works without issue on SQL Server 2008R2; however, when attempting the same when connected to my SQL Server 2012 instance, I encounter the following exception:

> System.Data.DuplicateNameException "A column named 'DatabaseName2' already belongs to this DataTable."

This exception occurs at the second line of the following code:

```
foreach (FileGroup fg in mySourceDatabase.FileGroups){
    foreach (DataFile df in fg.Files){
        string location = df.FileName;
        int extensionLoc = location.IndexOf(".mdf");
        if (extensionLoc > 0) {
            string newLocation = location.Substring(0, extensionLoc - 1);
            newLocation = newLocation + "_clone.mdf";
            restoreDB.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(df.Name, newLocation));
        }
        else {
            extensionLoc = location.IndexOf(".ndf");
            if (extensionLoc > 0) {
                string newLocation = location.Substring(0, extensionLoc - 1);
                newLocation = newLocation + "_clone.ndf";
                restoreDB.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(df.Name, newLocation));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The stack trace is as follows:

> at System.Data.DataColumnCollection.RegisterColumnName(String name, DataColumn column)
>   at System.Data.DataColumnCollection.BaseAdd(DataColumn column)
>   at System.Data.DataColumnCollection.AddAt(Int32 index, DataColumn column)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataProvider.InitSchemaTable(ArrayList parentProperties)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataProvider.Init(StatementBuilder sb, RetriveMode rm)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteSql.GetDataProvider(StringCollection query, Object con, StatementBuilder sb, RetriveMode rm)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.FillData(ResultType resultType, StringCollection sql, Object connectionInfo, StatementBuilder sb)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.FillDataWithUseFailure(SqlEnumResult sqlresult, ResultType resultType)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.BuildResult(EnumResult result)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.GetData(EnumResult erParent)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request req, Object ci)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.GetEnumeratorDataReader(Request req)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.InitChildLevel(Urn levelFilter, ScriptingPreferences sp, Boolean forScripting)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoCollectionBase.InitializeChildCollection(Boolean refresh)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoCollectionBase.GetEnumerator()
>   at [second line of my code above]

I have queried sys.master_files, but can't see any duplicates.

Can anybody suggest what the problem might be?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I never managed to figure out what caused the FileGroup.Files enumeration to fail; but I found that I could get the same information by inspecting the details of the files in the backup:

```
Restore restoreDB = new Restore();
restoreDB.Database = settings.DestDBName;
restoreDB.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
restoreDB.Devices.AddDevice(defaultBackupDir + backupFileRelativePath, DeviceType.File);
restoreDB.ReplaceDatabase = true;
restoreDB.NoRecovery = false;

DataTable fileList = restoreDB.ReadFileList(destinationServer);
foreach (DataRow row in fileList.Rows) {
    RelocateFile file = new RelocateFile();
    file.LogicalFileName = row[0].ToString();

    // Derive the physical location as the current physical location 
    string currentLocation = row[1].ToString();
    string extension = ".mdf";
    int extensionLoc = currentLocation.IndexOf(extension);
    if (extensionLoc <= 0) {
        extension = ".ldf";
        extensionLoc = currentLocation.IndexOf(extension);
    }
    if (extensionLoc <= 0) {
        extension = ".ndf";
        extensionLoc = currentLocation.IndexOf(extension);
    }
    if (extensionLoc <= 0) {
        continue;
    }
    string newLocation = currentLocation.Substring(0, extensionLoc);
    newLocation = newLocation + "_clone" + extension;
    file.PhysicalFileName = newLocation;

    restoreDB.RelocateFiles.Add(file);
}
```